# Elm How to make custom event decoder to get mouse x/y position at mouse-wheel-move

Tags: dom, typeerror, elm

I am trying to get the x and y coordinates of the mouse during a mouse-wheel-move event in the Elm 0.19 programming language. 
I attempt it with this package. See under "Advanced Usage":
https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/mpizenberg/elm-pointer-events/3.1.0/Html-Events-Extra-Wheel

The package itself did not describe a clear example so I looked for an example in a similar package.
See the example under "advanced usage" in this page:
https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/mpizenberg/elm-pointer-events/3.1.0/Html-Events-Extra-Mouse

This example is very similar to what I need, but I can also not get this to work. Get exactly the same problem.

Here is my code adapted from the example to fit with mouse wheel:

```
module WheelDecoder exposing(..)

import Html exposing (div, text)
import Html.Events.Extra.Wheel as Wheel
import Json.Decode as Decode


type alias WheelEventWithOffsetXY =
  { wheelEvent : Wheel.Event
  , offsetXY : {x: Float, y: Float}
  }

decodeWeelWithOffsetXY : Decode.Decoder WheelEventWithOffsetXY
decodeWeelWithOffsetXY =
  Decode.map2 WheelEventWithOffsetXY
    Wheel.eventDecoder
    offsetXYDecoder

offsetXYDecoder : Decode.Decoder {x: Float, y: Float}
offsetXYDecoder =
  Decode.map2 (\a b -> {x=a,y=b})
    (Decode.field "offsetY" Decode.float)
    (Decode.field "offsetY" Decode.float)

type Msg
  = WheelOffsetXY {x: Float, y: Float}

view = 
  div
    [ (onWheelOffsetXY (\wheelEvent -> WheelOffsetXY (wheelEvent.offsetXY))) ]
    [ (text "mousewheel here") ]


onWheelOffsetXY : (WheelEventWithOffsetXY -> msg) -> Html.Attribute msg
onWheelOffsetXY tag =
  let
    options = { stopPropagation = True, preventDefault = True }
    func = Decode.map tag decodeWeelWithOffsetXY
    attribute = Wheel.onWithOptions options func
  in
    attribute
```

When I try to compile with "elm make" I get the following error:

```
-- TYPE MISMATCH -------------------------------------- src/Map/WheelDecoder.elm

The 2nd argument to `onWithOptions` is not what I expect:

39|     attribute = Wheel.onWithOptions options func
                                                ^^^^
This `func` value is a:

    Decode.Decoder msg

But `onWithOptions` needs the 2nd argument to be:

    Wheel.Event -> msg

Hint: I always figure out the argument types from left to right. If an argument
is acceptable, I assume it is “correct” and move on. So the problem may actually
be in one of the previous arguments!
```

This error message makes sense as I can see there is a type mismatch, but I have no clue about how to solve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like `Wheel.eventDecoder` was meant to work with `Html.Events.on` or `Html.Events.onWithOptions` rather than `Wheel.onWithOptions`. These were removed in 0.19 in favor of `Html.Events.custom`, however, which is slightly different. Replacing `onWheelOffsetXY` with this seems to work:

```elm
onWheelOffsetXY : (WheelEventWithOffsetXY -> msg) -> Html.Attribute msg
onWheelOffsetXY tag =
  let
    options message =
        { message = message
        , stopPropagation = True
        , preventDefault = True
        }
    decoder =
        decodeWeelWithOffsetXY
        |> Decode.map tag 
        |> Decode.map options
  in
  Html.Events.custom "wheel" decoder
```

PS: There's a typo in `decodeWeelWithOffsetXY`, btw. I've left the typo in place.

PPS: Also, you're looking at outdated documentation. [Here's the documentation for the latest version](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/mpizenberg/elm-pointer-events/latest/Html-Events-Extra-Mouse).